# Kotlin Data class not respecting value passing order

Tags: kotlin

I have a strange behavior, I initialize a data class which expects 3 parameters but the order of the passed values is not respected and parameter 3 gets value of 2nd parameter passed, how come something like this cuold even happen?

```
data class PersonalSignMessage(val id: Long, val message: String, val address: String)
val signMessage = PersonalSignMessage(
                id,
                signingMessage,
                ethAddress
            )
```

My code was failing because of wrong values in the parameters, I cuoldn't believe it, since when debugging I could see that the passed data is correct, I put a breaktpoint after and I could see that signingMessage had the value of ethAddress. If I explicitly add the parameter names then it works:

```
        val signMessage = PersonalSignMessage(
            id = id,
            message = signingMessage,
            address = ethAddress
        )
```

Should this be an expected behavior???

Comment: Why the difference between `val signMessage = PersonalSignMessage(...)` and `val signMessage = Session.MethodCall.PersonalSignMessage(...)`? This is indeed very weird but there must be an explanation.

Comment: Makes me think there are two classes with the same name and different parameters.

Comment: To debug I'd advise wrapping those two parameters in an inline class so the compiler can distinguish them: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html
The compiler should then complain about the types which makes it much easier to trace back where you mixed them up, since you don't need to use the debugger at runtime for it.